# Any way to run commands/script after VS2015 Publish wizard has copied files to output?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015, automation

I have a very simple Windows service project I want to deploy to a server using Visual Studio 2015. I can successfully deploy using the Publish wizard (right-click on project -> Publish and deploy to `\\myserver\c$\somepath\`), but I need to 1) stop the service before publishing (so that the executable can be replaced), and 2) restart the service after the files have been copied.

I know how to start/stop services from the command line, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2164043/2978652) provides a way to do it directly in a build action. However, I can't seem to find a way to execute any action *after* VS has copied the files to the output directory on the server.

For example, I have tried adding the following to my .csproj file without luck:

```
<Target Name="Mytarget" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
  <Warning Text="After AfterPublish" />
</Target>
```

`Mytarget` executes before VS actually copies the files to the server, so evidently, I can't hook onto `AfterPublish`. I've also tried `PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder`, `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage`, and `MSDeployPublish` without luck (these don't seem to execute at all).

My end goal is to allow more-or-less one-click updating of the service, without having to log on to remote desktop and run a script manually after each update.

Is there any way I can have VS automatically execute an action after publishing a Windows service project to a server?